# Windows X.509 certificate private keys lost

Tags: windows, key-management, x.509, windows-server

Have the same certificates installed on several machines, but this happens on only one of them.
The certificates are self-signed certificates.
The certificates are used for WCF message security.

Installing the certificates with the following PS script (or manually through *Manage Computer Certificates*, doesn't make a difference):

```
function getKeyUniqueName($cert) {
     return $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
}

function getKeyFilePath($cert) {             
     return "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\$(getKeyUniqueName($cert))"
}

$certFromFile = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFile, $password)
$certFromStore = Get-ChildItem "$certStore" | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $certFromFile.Thumbprint}
$certExistsInStore = $certFromStore.Count -gt 0
$keyExists = $certExistsInStore -and ($certFromStore.PrivateKey -ne $null) -and (getKeyUniqueName($cert) -ne $null) -and (Test-Path(getKeyFilePath($certFromStore)))

Write-Host "CertExistsInStore:$certExistsInStore, keyExists: $keyExists"

if ((!$certExistsInStore) -or (!$keyExists)) {

    $keyFlags = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::MachineKeySet 
    $keyFlags = $keyFlags -bor [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::PersistKeySet
    $certFromFile.Import($certFile, $password, $keyFlags)

    $store = Get-Item "$certStore"
    $store.Open("ReadWrite")

    if ($certExistsInStore) {
        Write-Host "Private key missing: Re-adding certificate to store: $($certFromStore.Subject)"
        $store.Remove($certFromStore)
    }

    $store.Add($certFromFile)
    $store.Close()
}
```

Right after the certificates are installed the keys are there and I can verify the key files are there.
But then a day later the key files are gone (the certificates are still there).
The certificates have been originally installed a couple of months ago and everything was fine, then recently this key loss started happening.
It seems as though this loss is happening when windows update runs.

There are older certificates that were originally used for the same purpose installed on the same machine and the keys for these are fine.

Differences that I can see between the old ones and the new ones are:

1. The old ones had their private keys exportable and the new ones don't.
2. The old ones have a cusom-named key container and the new ones have auto-generated key container names (GUIDs).
3. The provider for the old certificates is "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" and for the new ones it's "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0".
4. The signature algorithm for the old ones is md5RSA and for the new ones it's SHA256RSA

I will try to follow points 1-3 above for the new certs and see if it helps, but curious to know what's actually happening.

Comment: Enable diagnostic logging. Start with [CAPI2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749296(v=ws.10)) and continue on as needed. You can even go as far as [logging/auditing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder) the actual certificate file.

Comment: You should update your script to use [PKIClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/).

Comment: @phbits, thanks for the suggestions! Enabled CAPI2 audit logs and added file deletion auditing on the MachineKeys folder. Will look at using PKIClient.